# Is firebase token is unique and permanent for every user?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am  developing   a web push notification app using javascript and PHP.
When a user grants permission for notification and receives a token from firebase.
I use ajax to store this token in database for that user.
**Is this token permanent?**
**Or It will change?**
*Actually, I want to generate a token for a user when he first signs up on the website, so it's necessary me to know how the token is managed by firebase.*

Comment: Tokens are not permanent, tokens do time out and when they do a new token must be requested. Looks like you are confusing API keys and tokens.

Answer (score 2):

The token may change when:

1. The app deletes Instance ID
2. The app is restored on a new device
3. The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
4. The user clears app data.

Assuming you are already listening on onNewToken of FirebaseMessagingService to get the initial token. Be alert to get the callback triggered in the above scenarios when a new token is assigned to your endpoint and don't miss a chance to update your app server with the new id and the concerned user.